# AutoML REST call with score_threshold returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: vb.net, automl

When I make a call to the Predictor and I add the score_threshold as shown below:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "image": {
      "imageBytes": "YOUR_IMAGE_BYTES"
    },
    "params": { "score_threshold": "0.0" },
  }
}
```

I get an error 400 Bad Request. The call works just fine (I get a prediction from AutoML) without the score_threshold clause. I'm using VB.Net for the call so wondering if there's a trick to formatting the call. I've also tried removing the quotes from the score as it is listed as a Float in the documentation with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

as in the example from GCP website it should be

```
params.scoreThreshold
```

so your json will be

```
{
  "payload": {
    "image": {
      "imageBytes": "YOUR_IMAGE_BYTES"
    },
    "params": { "scoreThreshold": 0.5 },
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that and still get the 400 with this code:

`    Dim sImageToCheck As String = "{ 'payload': { 'image': { 'imageBytes': '"

        Using imageStream As New FileStream(sFileToCheck, FileMode.Open)
        Dim bBytes As Byte()

        ReDim bBytes(CInt(imageStream.Length - 1))

        imageStream.Read(bBytes, 0, CInt(imageStream.Length))

        sImageToCheck &= Convert.ToBase64String(bBytes)

        End Using

    sImageToCheck &= "'}, 'params': { 'scoreThreshold': '0.5' }, } }"`